# MVC4 Mobile Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Since mvc4 mobile is still new and has limited info on it at the time, I was wondering if this mobile framework is meant for windows phone applications or is meant for mobile web browsers in general. In other words if i create a mvc4 mobile application, would it be compatible to use with all mobile browsers? Thanks for any info.

Comment: For me the obvious answer is that is made for mobile web browsers since is the results rendered via iis on http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is meant for mobile web browsers in general. More information and a list of how to test different browsers is located at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features.

Comment: My tutorial cited above is meant for generic devices with support for iPhone and other popular devices.